# finding equation of a line parallel to another line and passing a point

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

In homogeneous coordinates we have the point $M(1, 0, 2, 1)$ and the line
$$a:\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=2\lambda+3\mu  \\
y=1\lambda-2\mu\\
z=-1\lambda-\mu\\
t=3\lambda+\mu
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I have to find equation of a line $b$ which is parallel to the line $a$ and passes the point $M$.

My understanding is the following. Since the lines $a$ and $b$ are parallel, they have common infinite point, so I find the coordinates of an infinite point using the coefficients in front of the $\mu$, i.e. the point P(3, -2, -1, 0).

Having two points, I form the equation of the line $b$, i.e.
$$b:\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=1\lambda+3\mu  \\
y=0\lambda-2\mu\\
z=2\lambda-\mu\\
t=1\lambda+0\mu
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did with “using the coefficients in front of the $\mu$” was picking $\lambda=0,\mu=1$ which leads to $P(3,-2,-1,1)$ which is *not* at infinity!

The point at infinity is characterized by $t=3\lambda+\mu=0$ so for example $\lambda=1,\mu=-3$ (but any other multiple of this would work, too). With that you get $P(-7,7,2,0)$. Taking this correction into account, the rest of your approach looks good.